pytest does not show logs from failed tests
My pytest logs don't show what is happening during the execution of the failed (due to error) test.
Minimal reproducible example:
def integration_test():
     for i in range(100):
          logging.error("LOGGING TEST")
     errors = tested_function() # < Uncaught FileNotFound error happens at tested_function(); I expect pytest to catch and be able to handle this under the hood. 
     assert errors == 0.

The logging simply does not print the logging.error, not it doesn't print no logs from other parts of the test.
My pyproject.toml:
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = "DEBUG"
log_cli_format = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)"
log_cli_date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

log_file = "pytest.log"

Notably, this is the only test for the whole application yet, so my output is essentially collected 0 items / 1 error.
What's wrong?
Cheers.
Edit: 15 minutes later, I'm trying to trigger errors manually:
def integration_test():
    assert False
    raise Exception("How does this not fail?")
     for i in range(100):
          logging.error("LOGGING TEST")
     #errors = tested_function() # this is not commented out
    logging.info("this does not get printed")

This computes exactly as it has before. How are my tests not changing the output even though the intent has completely changed?

Your test name does not match the  standard test discovery. If you haven't configured that otherwise, it will not be found by pytest. Renaming to test_integration should help.
